# Use Linq to filter Hashtable based on a property of Values custom object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a synchronized Hashtable with int as the key, and a custom class called `Job` as the value.  I would like to filter this Hashtable based on a property in my Job class called `JobSize`.  `JobSize` is just an `enum` with values `Small`, `Medium`, and `Large`.

It's fine if it needs to be converted to another collection type to do this.

I know there's a slick LINQy way to do this, but I haven't found it yet...

Comment: If possible, you should use generic collections, in this case `Dictionary<int, Job>`.

Comment: @svick:  Yep, you're right.  I just got lazy about thread safety, but it's a better option... and ultimately, probably safer because I'll be more careful rather than just depending on a synchronized Hashtable to magically take care of everything for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like this will work for me:

```
var smallJobs = hashTable.Values.Cast<Job>().Where(job => job.JobSize == JobSize.Small);
```

The "`.Cast<Job>()`" is required because Hashtable is non-generic.

Comment: You ought to consider using a generic equivalent to `Hashtable` like Dictionary<T, T>.  Getting a synchronized Hashtable may not be solving all of your concurrency problems by itself.  Also, .NET 4 adds ConcurrentDictionary, which is thread-safe.

Comment: confirmed, this would do it :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to maintain the keys and values in your filtered `Hashtable`? If so, try this.

It'll filter the `Hashtable` and return the filtered results as a strongly typed `Dictionary<int,Job>`:

```
var filtered = yourHashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                            .Where(x => ((Job)x.Value).JobSize == JobSize.Small)
                            .ToDictionary(x => (int)x.Key, x => (Job)x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Job> smallJobs
  = hashTable.Values.Cast<Job>.Where(job => job.JobSize == JobSize.Small);
```

Comment: That's what I tried initially, but I got this error:

The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable <TSource> System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,bool>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

So, I did (or, I thought i did):

var smallJobs = hashTable.Values.Where<Job>(job => job.JobSize == JobSize.Small);

but then, of course, adding <Job> means that I can't convert from the non-generic type to the generic type.

Comment: `Hastable` is not generic, so you have to `Cast()` it first.

Comment: There is no `System.Collections.Generic.Hashtable`.